# Microsoft Store Desktop Bridge app cannot access "Offline Files" from network share

Tags: winforms, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge

Our .NET Windows Forms Desktop Bridge app on the Microsoft Store cannot read network shared files only in a very specific situation:

1. The network shared files have been marked as Offline Files in Windows (a Windows Sync Center feature), and
2. "Always available offline" has been enabled on the shared files, and
3. The network shared files are offline (disconnected from the share)

Below is a screenshot of an example shared/synced/offline file:

[image: offline-file]

When receiving a file path from the share in our software (e.g., U:\pdf\document.pdf), `File.Exists(string path)` returns false as if the file does not exist.  When using the file open dialog (`System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`) and navigating to the shared drive, the dialog states:

> An error occurred while reconnecting U: to \XXXXXXXXX\Share Microsoft
>   Windows Network: The local device name is already in use. This
>   connection has not been restored

[image: network-share-error]

Our app, like all Desktop Bridge apps, runs under full trust.  Our non-Microsoft Store distribution of the software, when run side-by-side with the Microsoft Store version, recognizes and opens the files fine.  Other UWP apps on the Store can open files in the network share as well.

What's going on?

**UPDATE:**

I added the permission `broadFileAccess` to the manifest per Nico Zhu's recommendation.  I'm testing by sideloading the app.  `File.Exists()` still returns false, but I get a different error from `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` when clicking the share location--a network error due to permissions:

[image: network-error]

Are there other permissions I need to add?  Is it possible that Desktop Bridge apps are required to use [FileOpenPicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker)?

**UPDATE 2:**

I looked at the manifests of other Desktop Bridge apps on the Store, and they only include the `runFullTrust` permission and not the `broadFileSystemAccess` permission.  However, they are able to open the "Offline Files" while my app cannot, leading me to believe that adding additional UWP permissions is not the solution.

**Sample Project**

You can reproduce the issue with this linked project (VS2017 WinForms 32-bit project with Inno Setup installer converted via DAC to an appx): [WinForms DAC Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NCEoYflYOSyuLL2Of-fhUrJmcCtUetYN)

The WinForms app has only a button that opens a `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`.  I sideloaded the appx with Windows 10 1709 and see the same error result as my app when trying to access the offline files location.  The network share is hosted by a Windows Server 2019 instance.

Comment: Have you add [`broadFileSystemAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) capability for your app.

Comment: I had not added `broadFileSystemAccess`.  I added it to the manifest but still get false for `File.Exists()`.  I get a different `Network Error` from the `OpenFileDialog` (see my post update).

Comment: After added broadFileSystemAccess capability, you need also open it in the OS setting->privacy-> File System.

Comment: Thank you--however the Privacy -> File System setting doesn't exist prior to Windows 10 1803.  What about previous OS versions which don't have this privacy setting, such as Windows 10 1709?  I've tested `broadFileSystemAccess` with 1709, but it does not resolve the issue.  Also, please see UPDATE 2 from my post above.  Other Desktop Bridge apps do not specify the `broadFileSystemAccess` permission in their manifests but still can access the "Offline Files" in file open dialogs whereas my app cannot.

Comment: Could you share a code sample that could reproduce this issue and  will be checked the problem directly.

Comment: Yes, I added a sample project to the post.  Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Sorry, I'm delay, I will check your demo.

Comment: Thanks, please let me know what you find.

Comment: I checked your code and above screen shot, I think if the remote disk disconnect, You will not use file picker to picker the file.

Comment: Do you mean that I should not use `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog`?  If not, what alternative do I have?  And, why does `OpendFileDialog` only fail within the Microsoft Store runtime and not within the runtime of my non-Microsoft Store build?

Comment: I mean you could use uwp Storage File picker to pick the file, but the remote disk offline, it will not success.

Comment: Well, then I'd be in the exact same position I am right now (using `OpenFileDialog` but not having access to the remote disk offline files).  If the files are offline and synced locally, then Windows creates a copy of them for viewing when the remote disk is offline.  I'd like to know the reason why the UWP runtime blocks `OpenFileDialog` from these files whereas a non-UWP runtime does not.